# How to send a simple string between two programs using pipes?

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I tried searching on the net, but there are hardly any resources. A small example would suffice.

EDIT
I mean, two different C programs communicating with each other. One program should send "Hi" and the other should receive it. Something like that.

Comment: Presumably you don't mean something like `ls | grep ".o"`? Perhaps a bit more explanation of what you do mean would help...

Comment: Come on man... a little effort.  Google "c pipes example code".  The first result is exact: http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html

Comment: I want communication between two completely different programs. I was not able to find a resource for that.

Comment: If you are not forking a process, then you need to look at "named pipes".

Answer (score 163, accepted):

A regular pipe can only connect two related processes.  It is created by a process and will vanish when the last process closes it.

A [**named pipe**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe), also called a FIFO for its behavior, can be used to connect two unrelated processes and exists independently of the processes; meaning it can exist even if no one is using it.  A FIFO is created using the [`mkfifo()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkfifo.html) library function.

### Example

**writer.c**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

    /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    /* write "Hi" to the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    write(fd, "Hi", sizeof("Hi"));
    close(fd);

    /* remove the FIFO */
    unlink(myfifo);

    return 0;
}
```

**reader.c**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
    printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

<sub>Note: Error checking was omitted from the above code for simplicity.</sub>

Comment: What is considered *related processes*?

Comment: Probably processes which are related via one or more parent/child relations (e.g. includes siblings). The common ancestor would have created the two ends of the pipe. Unrelated processes lack that common ancestor.

Comment: This will not work if the reader kicks off first. A quick fix would be to put the `open()` of the reader inside a loop. However +1 because you provide a two programs example.

Comment: I take it this example needs some tweaking to work on windows? unistd.h being POSIX and all...

Comment: Yes, it will need tweaking for Windows.  The [Wikipedia article on named pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) discusses some of the Unix/Windows differences and a quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=Windows+named+pipe+MSDN) can help with the Windows implementation.

Comment: @gsamaras hey man, how will we run this code I have no idea about socket programming, can you help me out?

Comment: I am sorry @Mohsin (great name!), but I haven't touched these for a while..I mean I barely remember how did I [answer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716255/why-does-this-program-print-forked-4-times/26716300#26716300), let alone sockets. Good luck!

Comment: @jschmier how will we exit from the continuous loop? I'm trying to implement between two functions once one of the functions sends the string and the other receives the string, it should exit. How can we do that?

Comment: Minor improvement: open calls block until the other side is open-ed. Might need " | O_NONBLOCK" in a real applications if they need to continue, do other things and read / write later, e.g. on a timer.

Comment: Can we pass std::string variable as a parameter in read and write methods ?

Answer (score 44):

From [Creating Pipes in C](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html), this shows you how to fork a program to use a pipe.  If you don't want to fork(), you can use [named pipes](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/named_pipes.html).

In addition, you can get the effect of `prog1 | prog2` by sending output of `prog1` to stdout and reading from `stdin` in `prog2`.  You can also read stdin by opening a file named `/dev/stdin` (but not sure of the portability of that).

```
/*****************************************************************************
 Excerpt from "Linux Programmer's Guide - Chapter 6"
 (C)opyright 1994-1995, Scott Burkett
 ***************************************************************************** 
 MODULE: pipe.c
 *****************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
        int     fd[2], nbytes;
        pid_t   childpid;
        char    string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
        char    readbuffer[80];

        pipe(fd);

        if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
        {
                perror("fork");
                exit(1);
        }

        if(childpid == 0)
        {
                /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
                close(fd[0]);

                /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
                write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
                exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
                /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
                close(fd[1]);

                /* Read in a string from the pipe */
                nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
                printf("Received string: %s", readbuffer);
        }

        return(0);
}
```

Comment: Hey Stephen, anyway I can use this code for two different functions? meaning writing to the pipe is done in one function and reading the pipe in another function?? a working code like this would be appreciated.

Comment: The "named pipes" link now redirects to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/. Archive for the old link: https://archive.is/VV7Mb

Answer (score 8):

```
dup2( STDIN_FILENO, newfd )
```

And read:

```
char reading[ 1025 ];
int fdin = 0, r_control;
if( dup2( STDIN_FILENO, fdin ) < 0 ){
    perror( "dup2(  )" );
    exit( errno );
}
memset( reading, '\0', 1025 );
while( ( r_control = read( fdin, reading, 1024 ) ) > 0 ){
    printf( "<%s>", reading );
    memset( reading, '\0', 1025 );
}
if( r_control < 0 )
    perror( "read(  )" );    
close( fdin );
```

But, I think that `fcntl` can be a better solution

```
echo "salut" | code
```

Answer (score 6):

What one program writes to stdout can be read by another via stdin. So simply, using c, write `prog1` to print something using `printf()` and `prog2` to read something using `scanf()`. Then just run

```
./prog1 | ./prog2
```

Answer (score 4):

[Here's a sample](http://www.itworld.com/nl/lnx_tip/07052002/):

```
int main()
{
    char buff[1024] = {0};
    FILE* cvt;
    int status;
    /* Launch converter and open a pipe through which the parent will write to it */
    cvt = popen("converter", "w");
    if (!cvt)
    {
        printf("couldn't open a pipe; quitting\n");
        exit(1)
    }
    printf("enter Fahrenheit degrees: " );
    fgets(buff, sizeof (buff), stdin); /*read user's input */
    /* Send expression to converter for evaluation */
    fprintf(cvt, "%s\n", buff);
    fflush(cvt);
    /* Close pipe to converter and wait for it to exit */
    status=pclose(cvt);
    /* Check the exit status of pclose() */
    if (!WIFEXITED(status))
        printf("error on closing the pipe\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The important steps in this program are:

1. The `popen()` call which establishes the association between a child process and a pipe in the parent.
2. The `fprintf()` call that uses the pipe as an ordinary file to write to the child process's stdin or read from its stdout.
3. The `pclose()` call that closes the pipe and causes the child process to terminate.

Comment: I think this example misses the point of the question, although I grant that the "converter" program is a different program.  The first comment addresses communication between completely independent programs that do not have a sibling/parent/second-cousin relationship.

Answer (score 2):

First, have program 1 write the string to `stdout` (as if you'd like it to appear in screen). Then the second program should read a string from `stdin`, as if a user was typing from a keyboard. then you run:

```
$ program_1 | program_2
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer might be helpful for a future Googler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){     
     int p, f;  
     int rw_setup[2];   
     char message[20];      
     p = pipe(rw_setup);    
     if(p < 0){         
        printf("An error occured. Could not create the pipe.");  
        _exit(1);   
     }      
     f = fork();    
     if(f > 0){
        write(rw_setup[1], "Hi from Parent", 15);    
     }  
     else if(f == 0){       
        read(rw_setup[0],message,15);       
        printf("%s %d\n", message, r_return);   
     }  
     else{      
        printf("Could not create the child process");   
     }      
     return 0;

}
```

You can find an advanced two-way pipe call example [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-demonstrate-fork-and-pipe/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable communication between two processes, you must determine if you're forking those processes or not. If you're forking them, then you can make use of [anonymous pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe). Otherwise, you can use [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).

#### Anonymous Pipes

Assuming you've declared the pipe before `fork()`, then a child process will inherit the parent process's pipe, both of which points to the same ends of the pipe. You can use this fact to send data between the processes.

For example, in the following program the parent process sends the string `Hello World!` to the child process, which then displays it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int pipefd[2];
    pipe(pipefd);

    int pid =  fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to fork process");
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        // the child process doesn't use the pipe's write and thus it closes it.
        close(pipefd[1]);

        // read data from the pipe's read end and store into buffer.
        char buffer[80];
        read(pipefd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("Received string: %s", buffer);

        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        // the parent process doesn't use the pipe's read end and thus it closes it.
        close(pipefd[0]);

        // write string to pipe's write end.
        char string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
        write(pipefd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));

        exit(0);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

#### Named Pipes

With a named pipe, you're using a file to transfer data between unrelated processes.

You can create a named pipe in the shell using `mkfifo`. Alternatively you can create it within a C program using the library function `mkfifo()`; you must include the `<sys/types.h>` and `<sys/stat.h>` libraries first.

##### Named pipe created interactively

We create the named pipe `pipefd` in the shell:

```
$ mkfifo pipefd
```

We implement the sender process as follows:

```c
// sender.c
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int pipefd = open("mypipe", O_WRONLY);

    // write string to pipe.
    char string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
    write(pipefd, string, (strlen(string)+1));

    close(pipefd);

    return(0);
}
```

We implement the receiver process as follows:

```c
// receiver.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int pipefd = open("mypipe", O_RDONLY);

    char buffer[80];
    read(pipefd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("Received string: %s", buffer);

    close(pipefd);

    return(0);
}
```

We compile both programs:

```
$ gcc sender.c -o sender
$ gcc receiver.c -o receiver
```

and run them:

```
$ ./sender &
[1] 97687
$ ./receiver
Received string: Hello, world!
```

As the output shows, the parent process sent the string to the child process which then displayed it.