# Piplining - Sending Strings Between Two Programs

Tags: c, pipe

I've been reading about pipelining and also read this topic - 
[How to send a simple string between two programs using pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784500/how-to-send-a-simple-string-between-two-programs-using-pipes)

I read @jschmier answer (the first one) - and I wonder how does it actually work ?
Do the programs writer.c and reader.c have to run simultaneously ? If they does , how reader.c is "informed" that writer.c has sent a string?

Those questions are mosly theoretical , but i'm really intrested to know how pipelining works.
Thanks in adnvnace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Do the programs writer.c and reader.c have to run simultaneously ?
```

They do.

```
If they does , how reader.c is "informed" that writer.c has sent a string?
```

Both programs open a special `pipe` device: `"/tmp/myfifo`. One opens for reading, and another one for writing. Kernel takes care of transferring data between them.

Please note, that pipes actually *require* concurrent reading and writing, as internal buffer is very small, and in absence of one activity blocks another.

How it works: if to simplify, the data *written* to a pipe goes from a process space into kernel and into *reader* process. Usually developers try to use non-blocking calls, as blocking program execution in case one process is busy is not acceptable.

For more information on pipes, you can read Linux documentation on the subject: http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd like to know - once the writer.c file writes to the pipeline , the reader.c file is getting an "alert" that new data has been written to the pipleine? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, it works that way. Reader will receive data as soon as write writes it. There is no buffering invoked, as with stdio operations.