# Effective debugging techniques for unix pipes?

Tags: unix, pipe, named-pipes

I'm very new to unix programming, so please bear with me.  :)

I'd like to pass data between two processes.  I was going to use named pipes, but read about these "half-duplex" pipes, and it was very intriguing, so I figured that I would give them a try first.

I have two issues with these pipes thus far:

1. I haven't figured out how to get execlp to run another application from my child process
2. Even if I could, debugging is tough because I've only been able to set breakpoints in the parent process

I'm sure there are reasons for these issues.  I am starting to wonder if it makes sense to just forget about them and just use named pipes so I can debug each application in a separate instance of eclipse.

If there is any relevant information, please let me know.  The code I am using is essentially what it found on [tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html).

EDIT -- I renamed my question to be about unix pipes in general.  I had assumed that for named pipes, I wouldn't have to use fork(), but all of the examples I have seen so far require it.  So regardless of half-duplex or named pipes, I'm going to need to be able to debug the child process somehow!

EDIT #2 -- [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784500/how-to-send-a-simple-string-between-two-programs-using-pipes) clearly shows that what I had seen before (on an IBM link) regarding named pipes wasn't necessarily true.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend two tools:

- `strace -ff` should give you a trace of all significant events, allowing you to examine in detail what's going on, namely, all reads and writes;
- `lsof` allows you to dump file descriptors of involved processes, clearly showing what is connected to what else and, in particular, if you forgot to `close()` some descriptors and the whole thing deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into these tools once I have my code running!