# Linux inter-processes communication

Tags: c, linux

I have to implement a testing program(quiz), which besides displaying the question and reading the answer, it has to display the time left at each one minute past. After finishing the examination time, by finishing the questions or by running out of time,the program has to get back from the beginning, when before the start, we enter the name of the candidate. This implementation has to be done using processes. Below is the code that i have written so far. The problem is that i am not sure that i am making a good communication between the process and the subprocesses, especially because i am not using a pipe. Some opinions?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

#define T 180

void firstChildAction(){
    static const char filename[] = "/home/osystems01/laura/text";
    char question[100];
    char answer[100];

    FILE *file = fopen(filename,"r");
    if(file != NULL){
        while(fgets(question,sizeof question,file) != NULL){
            fputs(question, stdout);
            scanf("%s",&answer);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    else{
        perror(filename);
    }
}

void secondChildAction(){
    int i;
    for(i = T; i >= 0; i-=60){
        if( i/60 != 0){
            printf("You have %d %s left.\n", i/60,(i/60 >   1)?"minutes":"minute");
            sleep(60);
        }
        else{
            printf("The time is over\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    pid_t pidA;
    pid_t pidB;
    pid_t wPid;
    char name[20];
    while(1){
        printf("Enter the candidate name or Quit to exit: \n");
        scanf("%s",&name);
        if(strcmp(name,"Quit") == 0 || strcmp(name,"quit") == 0){
            printf("The program is terminating.....\n");
            break;
        }
        else{
            pidA = fork();
            if(pidA == 0){
                firstChildAction();
                exit(0);
            }
            else{
                pidB = fork();
                if(pidB == 0){
                    secondChildAction();
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            int status;
            while(wPid = wait(&status)) > 0 ){
                if(WIFEXITED(status)){
                    int result = WEXITSTATUS(status);
                    printf("Exit status of %d is %d\n", wPid, result);
                    if(wPid == pidA){
                        kill(pidB,SIGTERM);
                        kill(pidA,SIGTERM);
                    }
                    else if(wPid == pidB){
                        kill(pidA,SIGTERM);
                        kill(pidB,SIGTERM);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggestions:
* Use locks (for the file in your case)
* Or use pipes ;) : http://stackoverflow.com/q/2784500/1175253

Comment: I am new to this and i don't understand something. I have to use a pipe for the reading from file(action made by the child) and display the question(action made by the parent)? i am confused

Comment: Moved to an answer for editing.

Comment: Use FIFOs for inter process communication: http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes as such don't require you to provide a regular file, but they can have a unique, globally visible name, which is provided by a (unused) filename you have to specify. The contents of the file, if any, is handled by the library.

There are (simple) pipes for communication among related processes (such as a child and a parent process in the same process hierarchy) where the pipe handle can easily be passed to other processes.

The other flavor is called 'named pipes' for processes with any relation, where one can lookup the pipe handle using the global name (as explained in the answer of the question I linked). You can think of a pipe as of a directly connected speaking tube, allowing two processes to chitchat about whatever they like, using read and write functions. On Linux, a pipe is a simplex (at a time, one talks, the other one listens). One would nee two pipes for bidirectional async IO in this case (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53641/how-to-make-bidirectional-pipe-between-two-programs). The immediate buffer for input and output is abstracted. Its just like with network sockets.

I'd suggest to compile this nice example in the accepted answer to play around with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2789967/1175253

#### Edit

Example code with error handling. Treat pipe.h & pipe.c as a library (link NamedPipeReader and NamedPipeWriter against it).
This code would need further testing, however, the code is able to (re)open named pipes in any order.

---

**pipe.h**

```
#ifndef PIPE_H_
#define PIPE_H_

//C headers
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>

//Linux headers
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

int open_named_pipe(const char* const name, const int permissions, const int mode, int* pipe_created);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* PIPE_H_ */
```

---

**pipe.c**

```
#include "pipe.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int open_named_pipe(const char* const name, const int permissions, const int mode, int* pipe_created)
{
    int fd;

    assert(name);
    assert(permissions);
    assert(pipe_created);

    //Create or use an existing pipe special file
    if (0 == mkfifo(name, permissions))
    {
        *pipe_created = 1;
        printf("Successfully created named pipe '%s'\n", name);
    }
    else
    {
        switch (errno)
        {
        case EEXIST:
            //this is OK, as the other process might already has created the special file
            printf("Opened existing named pipe '%s'\n", name);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create or access named pipe '%s'\n", name);
            perror("    ");
            return -1;
        };
    }

    fd = open(name, mode);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not open pipe for writing");
        if (*pipe_created)
        {
            if (0 == unlink(name))
            {
                *pipe_created = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                perror("Failed to unlink named pipe");
            }
        }
    }

    return fd;
}
```

---

**NamedPipeReader.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include "pipe.h"

//Globals
const char* const pipe_name = "/tmp/myfifo";
const int pipe_permissions = 0600;
const size_t read_buffer_size = 1024; //[bytes]
const size_t read_retry_delay = 25000; //[us]

int fd = -1;
int pipe_created = 0;
char* read_buffer = NULL;

//Handles EPIPE signal
void signal_handler(int signal)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "cought signal %d\n", signal);
}

//Handles cleanup on exit
void exit_handler(void)
{
    if (read_buffer)
        free(read_buffer);

    if (fd >= 0)
        close(fd);

    //if this process created the FIFO, we unlink it
    if (pipe_created == 0)
        unlink(pipe_name);
}

int main()
{
    //Locals
    int run = 1;
    int received = 0;

    //Install the exit handler
    atexit(&exit_handler);
    signal(EPIPE, signal_handler);
    signal(EACCES, signal_handler);

    //Allocate the buffer
    read_buffer = (char*) malloc(read_buffer_size);
    if (!read_buffer)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate buffer");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    restart: ;

    //Close if already open
    if(fd >= 0)
        close(fd);
    //Create or use an existing pipe special file
    fd = open_named_pipe(pipe_name, pipe_permissions, O_RDONLY, &pipe_created);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (run)
    {
        assert(fd >= 0);
        assert(read_buffer_size > 1);

        received = read(fd, read_buffer, read_buffer_size - 1);

        if (received > 0)
        {
            //add a NUL char for string termination
            read_buffer[received] = '0';
            printf("local process %llu received: %s\n", (unsigned long long) getpid(), read_buffer);
        }
        else if (received == 0)
        {
            //EOF reached, this happens in case the writer has closed its handle.
            //Perform a delayed restart and recreate the named pipe
            usleep(read_retry_delay);
            printf("Restarting...\n");
            goto restart;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (errno)
            {
            case EAGAIN:
                //Wait, if the pipe is empty,
                //happens when opened with the O_NONBLOCK flag
                usleep(read_retry_delay);
                break;
            case EPIPE:
            case EBADF:
            case EBADFD:
                perror("Pipe error");
                printf("Restarting...\n");
                goto restart;
            default:
                perror("Pipe error");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            };
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

**NamedPipeWriter.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include "pipe.h"

//Globals
const char* const pipe_name = "/tmp/myfifo";
const int pipe_permissions = 0600;
const size_t write_buffer_size = 1024; //[bytes]
const size_t write_retry_delay = 25000; //[us]
const size_t write_interval = 1000000;

int fd = -1;
int pipe_created = 0;
char* write_buffer = NULL;

//Handles EPIPE signal
void signal_handler(int signal)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "cought signal %d\n", signal);
}

//Handles cleanup on exit
void exit_handler(void)
{
    if (write_buffer)
        free(write_buffer);

    if (fd >= 0)
        close(fd);

    //if this process created the FIFO, we unlink it
    if (pipe_created == 0)
        unlink(pipe_name);
}

//Main Function
int main()
{
    //Locals
    int run = 1;
    int sent = 0;
    int msg_len = 0;

    //Install the exit handler
    atexit(&exit_handler);
    signal(EPIPE, signal_handler);
    signal(EACCES, signal_handler);

    //Allocate the buffer
    write_buffer = (char*) malloc(write_buffer_size);
    if (!write_buffer)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate buffer");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    restart: ;

    //Close if already open
    if(fd >= 0)
        close(fd);
    //Create or use an existing pipe special file
    fd = open_named_pipe(pipe_name, pipe_permissions, O_WRONLY, &pipe_created);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (run)
    {
        //Print message into the buffer
        msg_len = snprintf(write_buffer, write_buffer_size, "Greetings from process %llu\n", (unsigned long long) getpid());

        {
            char* msg_ptr = write_buffer;
            char* msg_end = write_buffer + msg_len;
            while (msg_ptr != msg_end)
            {
                assert(fd >= 0);
                assert(msg_ptr < msg_end);
                sent = write(fd, msg_ptr, msg_end - msg_ptr);
                if (sent > 0)
                {
                    msg_ptr += sent;
                }
                else if (sent == 0)
                {
                    //retry delay for nonblocking writes
                    usleep(write_retry_delay);
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (errno)
                    {
                    case EAGAIN:
                        //Wait, if the pipe is full,
                        //happens when opened with the O_NONBLOCK flag
                        usleep(write_retry_delay);
                        break;
                    case EPIPE:
                    case EBADF:
                    case EBADFD:
                        perror("Pipe error");
                        printf("Restarting...\n");
                        goto restart;
                    default:
                        perror("Pipe error");
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                    };
                }
            }

            printf("Written: %s\n", write_buffer);
            usleep(write_interval);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what i am doing wrong, but none of those examples are not working. I compile and run and then nothing. i don't have any error message, it simply does nothing

Comment: Sorry, I that example implementation works the other way around, writer first, then the reader. But I'll provide you an example, in which it doesn't matter (as processes should be able to communicate regardless of startup order)

Comment: Oops... And as I mentioned in a deleted comment, don't connect the processes with another pipe. Use separate terminals for both examples.