# can a linux shared library open, display and printf to terminal?

Tags: javascript, linux, terminal, firefox-addon, printf

I am creating a Firefox extension that calls a Linux shared library via the js-ctypes mechanism.  I want my extension to display debug information on a standard terminal by calling a function in my shared library which then simply calls printf() to display the debug string on a terminal.

However, my application has no terminal.  So, is there a way my shared library can open, display and printf() to display such messages?

Yes, I know about the built-in error and browser windows.  But for obscure reasons I want to send my debug messages in a terminal window.

So, how can my shared library open and display a terminal to printf() into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you're on Linux anyway, when running Firefox from the command line, it will print some stuff to `stdout` (or was it `stderr`) already. Same on MAC. Windows may need the [`-console` switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-console). Your library that was loaded via js-ctypes could just use `printf()` and/or `fprintf(stderr,...)`. I seem remember using `printf` myself when developing js-ctypes stuff in the past.
- You can also use [`dump`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.dump) in JS code. This will only ever dump to the terminal, but not the Browser Console.
- Lastly the [`Components.utils.reportError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.reportError) enables you to print arbitrary messages to th global Browser Console (formerly Error Console). `Cu.reportError` is basically a [shortcut to `nsIConsoleService`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/js/xpconnect/src/XPCComponents.cpp#2627), which will also generate appropriate location information.

Comment: At the top of my extension javascript program is this line: `var econsole = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIConsoleService);` :::  Then all over my extension program are print statements that look like this: `econsole.logStringMessage("funcname() : variable = " + variable);` ::: This prints to both the error console and browser console.  Is this inferior to what you mention, or the same?

Comment: Also, strange that `dump(string);` and `window.dump(string);` do not output anything into the error console or browser console even though `about:config` shows `browser.dom.window.dump.enabled` is `true`.  But all my `econsole.logStringMessage()` do output to both the error console and browser console.  Hmmm.

Comment: `Cu.reportError` uses `nsIConsoleService`, but does generate proper error messages linking the source when passed errors and exceptions. `dump` will only ever print to the terminal console (if a stdout/sterr is attached to the program, e.g. when run from command line).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a simple server that connects to a named pipe and reads data, then prints it to its stdout. It would just be a simple program that connects to a pipe (like a file), and reads from it.

You can use mkfifo to create the named pipe, and your javascript app can write to it, just like you would a file.

A related question is here: [How to send a simple string between two programs using pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784500/how-to-send-a-simple-string-between-two-programs-using-pipes)

You can use the command line mkfifo tool, or use the standard C function.