# Named pipes Example in C

Tags: c, output, named-pipes

Reader Side,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
        int fd;
        char buff[100];
        fd = open ("MyPipes",O_RDONLY);
        read (fd, buff, 100);
        printf ("%s\n",buff);
        close(fd);
}
```

Writer Side,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

char *ptr = "Akshit Soni";
int main()
{
        int fd;
        fd = open ("MyPipes",O_WRONLY);
        write (fd, ptr, strlen(ptr));
        close (fd);
}
```

Problem is that reader program outputs gets garbage value.

Comment: Where does the pipes bit come in?

Comment: where's the garbage value ??? :P

Comment: \0 not an issue ... i removed .. i put that for just testing purpose :)

Comment: @EdHeal, "MyPipes" is probably a named pipe. See http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2789967/1967396 for a working example of how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your (first) problem lies here:

```
write (fd, ptr, strlen(ptr));
```

The `strlen` of `"Akshit Soni"` does *not* include the trailing NUL character. You need to use `strlen (ptr) + 1` as the length.

You should also allow for the fact that `read()` may not return all the bytes you asked for (100) nor all the bytes that were sent (12 including the NUL). It's possible (for reasons such as timing or interrupts) that only *part* of the data may be read by a single call to `read()`.

To allow for that, you could try something like:

```
int main()
{
    int fd;
    char buff[100];
    fd = open ("MyPipes",O_RDONLY);
    int sz = read (fd, buff, 100);
    while ((sz > 0) && (buff[sz-1] != '\0')) {
        printf ("%*.*s", sz-1, sz-1, buff);
        sz = read (fd, buff, 100);
    }
    if (sz > 0)
        printf ("%s\n",buff);
    close(fd);
}
```

---

As an aside, make sure you have actually *created* the named pipe before you run the code, with something like (from `bash`):

```
mkfifo MyPipes
```

Comment: Yes. Need `strlen(ptr) + 1`. Well spotted.

Comment: It is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: @Axit `strlen(ptr) + 1 not working` is _not_ a very useful statement, especially when it works fine here. Are you still getting garbage at the end of the string? Is there a compile problem? Has your PC melted? A little more specificity would help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you open things in the right order; first open the pipe for write, then for read. You don't test that you don't have a NULL response to the opening of the pipe, and you may well be looking at garbage. Always test the return value of your functions...

Comment: Where is the pipe? It is just a file

Comment: Named pipe is new concept for me... i see this example on internet and try to implement @Ed Heal

Answer (score 0):

1. it is not correct to create named pipe.
   use mkfifo to create it
2. for create file, might need to use more flags, assuming there is no such file named MyPipes exist already.
   fd = open ("MyPipes",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);
   no O_CREAT, there is no file to be created.
3. write (fd, ptr, strlen(ptr));
   change it to 
   write (fd, ptr, strlen(ptr)+1);

strlen will return the length withou "\0".

Answer (score 0):

You failed to add the proper flag when `open`.

Try this:

fd = open ("mypipe11",O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);

**EDIT:**

Create the named pipe in writer before open using [mkfifo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

char *ptr = "Akshit Soni";
int main()
{
        int fd;

        /* Create named pipe */
        mkfifo("MyPipes", 0666);

        /* open named pipe */
        fd = open ("MyPipes",O_WRONLY);

        write (fd, ptr, strlen(ptr));
        close (fd);
}
```

@paxdiablo already given command line method of creating named pipe.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for your valid info. How about using `mknod` before `open` to create fifo?.