# cannot switch to blocking mode using fcntl in linux

Tags: c, linux, io, nonblocking, fcntl

I have a sample program:

```
int main()
{
   const char* fn = "/tmp/tmpfifo";
   int i = mkfifo(fn, 0666);
   int fd = open(fn, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
   int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
   flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
   fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);

   char buf[1024];
   int rd= read(fd, buf, 100);
   cout << rd << endl;
   remove(fn);
   return 0;
}
```

It seems that after removing the non-blocking flag from the file descriptor, the `read` call should block until something is written into the FIFO, but my program always runs without blocking and `rd=0` result. Can you please explain this behaviour? Thanks!

Comment: looks like C++ and not C. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784500/how-to-send-a-simple-string-between-two-programs-using-pipes

Comment: is c++, c difference important here?

Comment: When you read from fifo with `rd = 0` as result, is there any change in `errno` value?

Comment: `cout << rd << endl;` is pure C++ but everything is explain in the previous link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784500/how-to-send-a-simple-string-between-two-programs-using-pipes

Comment: Yes, that can easily be replaced with a `printf` and is not relevant to the discussion.

Comment: Have you examined `flags` before/after `flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;` to insure the bitwise negation is accomplishing what you need? Why not set `O_RDONLY` instead `flags` with your 2nd call to `fcntl` as a test.?

Comment: The writer should create the fifo first

Comment: @AntoJurković errno doesn't change.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried setting `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY) that didn't change anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is expected. You've done the following:

1. Opened the read end of the FIFO using `O_NONBLOCK`, so that a writer need not be present on the FIFO. This guarantees that the `open()` will immediately  succeed.
2. Disabled `O_NONBLOCK` before subsequent reads. You've now taken yourself back to a position that is equivalent to the standard (blocking) case where a FIFO had a reader and writer, but the writer closed the FIFO. At that point, the reader should see end-of-file, which is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your code and at first glance it seems like it should work. There are no errors returned, you don't seem to be breaking any rules, but it's just not blocking.

So I went ahead and traced the `read` call to see what it was doing:

[image: ftrace]

And it goes all the way to [the pipe_read function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/pipe.c?v=3.2#L349) without any attempt to block. Once it's there it realizes there's nobody on the other side of the pipe and returns EOF.

So this is apparently by design, but with a pipe only the `open` call will try to block if there's no writer, once `open` returns it's just assumed that there must be a writer at the other end of that pipe or that you're nonblocking and ready to handle that. And it sort of makes sense. If you're trying to `read` from a pipe but the writer is gone (or was never there in the first place), you don't want to keep waiting there forever.

If you want to wait until a writer opens the pipe, don't use `O_NONBLOCK` in the `open` call. If you do use `O_NONBLOCK` in `open`, then there might not be anyone at the other end of the pipe and the `read` calls may just return EOF without blocking.

So in short make sure there's someone at the other end of the pipe when you're reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange! I tried a code which opens the file without O_NONBLOCK and then procedes in 3 stages. The 3rd stage doesn'act correctly althoug the O_NONBLOCK flag results reset!

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
   char buf[1024];
   int rd;
   const char* fn = "prova.txt";
   int i = mkfifo(fn, 0666);
   int fd = open(fn, O_RDONLY); // | O_NONBLOCK);
   int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
   //flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
   printf("1) Waits!\t\tflags=0%08o\n",flags);

   rd= read(fd, buf, 100);
   printf("%d %o\n",rd,flags);

   flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
   printf("2) Doesn't wait!\tflags=0%08o\n",flags);
   fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);
   rd= read(fd, buf, 100);
   printf("%d %o\n",rd,flags);  

   //This doen't act the flag ????
   flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
   fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);
   flags=fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
   printf("3) Waits!\t\tflags=0%08o\n",flags);
   rd= read(fd, buf, 100);
   printf("%d %o\n",rd,flags);

   puts("End!");
   return 0;
}
```

Here is the command sequence and the output:

```
sergio@zarathustra:~$ ./a.out &
[2] 6555
sergio@zarathustra:~$ echo xxx >> prova.txt
1) Waits!       flags=000100000
4 100000
2) Doesn't wait!    flags=000104000
0 104000
3) Waits!       flags=000100000
0 100000
End!
sergio@zarathustra:~$
```