# communication of processes over named pipe

Tags: pipe, fifo

I want to create communication between different scripts using a named pipe. I read several examples but in these all examples strings are written to pipe.

So my question is how can I write a script to pipe in c? Should it be anything like this?

`write(w_fd,"/.script")`

and what is about reading from pipe?

Comment: What does it even mean "writing a script to pipe"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send a simple string between two programs using pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784500/how-to-send-a-simple-string-between-two-programs-using-pipes)

Comment: I mean I dont write a string like "hello" into a pipe, but a script, which should be executed. For example I have a master script and several other scriptes, which send a command to a mster script.