# Exchange a variable beetwen cpp programs

Tags: c++

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and i need to exchange an int variable from a cpp program to another.
program A.cpp has to work with an int variable,but the value of this int variable has to be define in program B.cpp

In a very simple example:

B.cpp:

```
int x=0;
cout<<"define x\t";
cin>>x;
```

A.cpp:

```
int y=0;
y=x+5;
cout<<y;
```

A.cpp and B.cpp are two different cpp programs and variable x should not to be static,after i execute A.cpp i have to change x value without exit from the execution

How can i do this?

Comment: a cpp is a source file but not a program per se. Do both A and B contain a main ?

Comment: Are they really different programs? In that case you might be looking for shared memory. If they're simply different source-files, that would simplify matters greatly.

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question one or two days ago?

Comment: they calls too header and have too much code. SO,yes i can do it,but i would prefer a cleaner way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way will be to create a named pipe. Under linux, you can use [`mkfifo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html) in `A.cpp` to create the pipe, then use it as an ordinary file. Open it for writing in `A.cpp` and write your `y` there, and open the same pipe in `B.cpp` for reading, and read `x` from there.

There are other approaches, but this seems to be the simplest.

See also [How to send a simple string between two programs using pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784500/how-to-send-a-simple-string-between-two-programs-using-pipes)

For a more detalied discussion, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication . I think most worth mentioning for your case are

> Socket — A data stream sent over a network interface, either to a different process on the same computer or to another computer on the network.

and

> Shared memory — Multiple processes are given access to the same block of memory which creates a shared buffer for the processes to communicate with each other.

Comment: cuold you do a the code example of above?? Sorry but i have never used pipes and i' m a new ubuntu user.

Comment: @MarcelloChiurazzi, please see another question that I refer to

Comment: I saw it and i understand how it works. i hope il will work for me. I will let you know. Anyway thanks ;)

Comment: the example aboout pipes is in c,how i can change it in c++?

Comment: @MarcelloChiurazzi, I think it will compile under C++ too. You can change the `open`/`close` work with files to streams, just as you usually work with files in a c++-program. You would also probably change `char*` to `string`, but as you have a number, not a string, this is not a problem.

Comment: I copy exactly the full example about reader and writer,if i compile both there are no problems but if i run writer or reader nothing happens!

Comment: You need to start both of them simultaneously, how else do you want them to pass data?

Comment: sure,i try `rosrun .... writer | reader ` but i have this error:
`No command 'reader' found, did you mean:
 Command 'render' from package 'raster3d' (multiverse)
reader: command not found´