# Linux : pipeline output of one program to another

Tags: c, linux

I have made two simple programs :

**out.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for(;;)
    {
        x = rand();
        printf("%d\n", x % 100);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**in.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    for(;;)
    {
        scanf("%d",&x);
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am running it like `./out | ./in` , but i am not getting any print. What's the correct way to run in such a way as to pipeline the inputs

Comment: This is one link I found, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40277/is-there-a-way-to-pipe-the-output-of-one-program-into-two-other-programs, but i don't think that is relevant in this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784500/how-to-send-a-simple-string-between-two-programs-using-pipes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be fixed by flushing stdout in your out.c program. You need to do this because it doesn't automatically get flushed if stdout isn't a tty, depending on your operating system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for(;;)
    {
        x = rand();
        printf("%d\n", x % 100);
        fflush(stdout); // <-- this line
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```