# Named pipe results in infinite loop/no output

Tags: c, macos, pipe, ipc, named-pipes

I've been trying to create a simple program which uses a named pipe to communicate between processes. I've tried doing this on OS X Yosemite as well as Ubuntu Linux 14.04 (virtualised on Parallels) and below is the code for a program which *should* have 3 processes which communicate via the same named pipe.

## My Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void proc1(char *named_pipe) {

  printf("Proc 1\n");

  int fd;
  char *mess1;

  mess1 = "Message from \"proc1\".";
  fd = open(named_pipe, O_WRONLY);
  if(fd == -1) {
    printf("error : opening\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  printf("Opened\n");
  if(write(fd, mess1, sizeof(mess1)) == -1) {
    perror("error : writing\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  close(fd);

  printf("End of Process 1.\n");

}

void proc2(char *named_pipe) {

  int fd;
  char buf[50];
  char *mess2;

  fd = open(named_pipe, O_RDONLY);
  read(fd, buf, 50);
  printf("Received : %s\n", buf);
  close(fd);

  mess2 = "Message from \"proc2\".";
  fd = open(named_pipe, O_WRONLY);
  write(fd, mess2, sizeof(mess2));
  close(fd);

  printf("End of Process 2.\n");

}

void proc3(char *named_pipe) {

  int fd;
  char buf[50];

  fd = open(named_pipe, O_RDONLY);
  read(fd, buf, 50);
  printf("Received : %s\n", buf);
  close(fd);

  printf("End of Process 3.\n");

}

int main() {

  char tube[4] = "tube";

  printf("### Start of program ###\n");

  if(mkfifo(tube, 0600) == -1) {
    perror("Problem creating named pipe.\n");
    exit(99);
  }

  proc1(tube);
  proc2(tube);
  proc3(tube);

  printf("### End of program ###\n");

  return 0;
}
```

## My Output

```
### Start of program ###
Proc 1
```

And then nothing happens, apart from the cursor blinking indicating (?) that the program is still running. Thus, the code seems to loop infinitely every time I run this program without ever telling me why.

## My Question

What really puzzles me though is that even a verified-to-be-working piece of code I found on this site while researching this issue *also* results in the same infinite loop/no output; [see that code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784500/how-to-send-a-simple-string-between-two-programs-using-pipes). Could it then be an issue with my operating system? Bear in mind the exact same result occurs on both OSX and Ubuntu.

*update*

## Solution

(Thanks to @Sami Kuhmonen)

I needed to run the 2 programs (from the linked code) at the same time. Feel a bit silly now!

Comment: You only have one process, so there's no IPC

Comment: tube needs to be char[5] for ending 0, else filename will be a mess

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Hi, thanks a million for the comment. My only question is then why does the code in the linked question not work either? Should I be running the 2 programs at the same time?

Comment: @daire16 The writer and reader must be run at the same time, otherwise they will block unless nonblocking open is used

Comment: @KaiIskratsch thanks for that, I was wondering why the pipe had a funny name alright!

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen ...egg on my face, ran the 2 programs at the same time and it worked no problem. Thanks a million!