# FIFO pipe returns 0 instead of correct integer?

Tags: c, file, ipc, named-pipes, fifo

I am attempting to implement a basic communication between two processes. I intend for each process to receive a piece of information then transmit one back. I am new to pipes so have attempted this using this code example:
[How to send a simple string between two programs using pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784500/how-to-send-a-simple-string-between-two-programs-using-pipes)

I set up the code and it works fine, I then duplicated the code for a second pipe in order to receive another integer. However my second pipe does not transmit the integer, the program receives a 0 instead.

program1.c:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024
int main()
{
    int fd; // file descriptor
    int fd_b;
    int data = 5;
    int buf; // buffer from fifo
    char * fifo_one = "/tmp/fifo_one";
    char * fifo_two = "/tmp/fifo_two";

    // create fifo
    mkfifo(fifo_one, 0666);

    // write to FIFO
    fd = open(fifo_one, O_WRONLY);
    write(fd, &data, sizeof(&data));
    close(fd);

    // remove FIFO
    unlink(fifo_one);

    // receive from FIFO
    fd_b = open(fifo_two, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd_b, &buf, MAX_BUF);
    printf("Received: %d\n", buf);
    close(fd_b);

    return 0;
}
```

program2.c:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main()
{
    int fd; // file descriptor
    int fd_b;
    char * fifo_one = "/tmp/fifo_one";
    char * fifo_two = "/tmp/fifo_two";
    int buf; // buffer from fifo
    int ret_dat; // return data

    // receive data from fifo
    fd = open(fifo_one, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, &buf, MAX_BUF);
    printf("Received: %d\n", buf);
    close(fd);

    // decide return
    if (buf == 5) {
        ret_dat = 10;
    }

    // send data back

    // create fifo
    mkfifo(fifo_two, 0666);

    // write to FIFO
    fd_b = open(fifo_two, O_WRONLY);
    write(fd_b, &ret_dat, sizeof(&ret_dat));
    close(fd_b);

    // remove FIFO
    unlink(fifo_sendBal);

    return 0;
}
```

The second program receives the 5, but does not send back 10 successfully,

I understand that timings effect IPC so I have tried using sleep after certain events but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: You should add some error checking (`perror(3)`).

Comment: Unrelated: `write(fd, &data, sizeof(&data));` is terribly wrong, you dont need the ampersand. just `write(fd, &data, sizeof data);` will do.[and you should also check the return value you get from read() and write()] **3)** and `read(fd_b, &buf, MAX_BUF);` is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Both `read()` and `write()` either read or write *up to* the number of bytes requested.  They can and often do return numbers less than the requested value.  There aren't many uses where the value returned can be safely ignored, especially if you have to handle errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The second program receives the 5, but does not send back 10 successfully ?*  The property  of `FIFO` inter process communication created by calling `mkfifo()` is that  **both process should alive to communicate** each other. From the manual page of [mkfifo](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo)

> Once you have created a `FIFO` special file in this way, **any process
>   can open it for reading or writing**, in the same way as an ordinary
>   file. However, **it has to be open at both ends simultaneously before
>   you can proceed to do any input or output operations on it**. Opening
>   a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the
>   same FIFO for writing, and vice versa. See `fifo(7)` for nonblocking
>   handling of FIFO special files.